# Custom Tkinter Widget (ScrollFrame) placement

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have created a custom scrollable Frame, full code here:

```
from tkinter import Frame, Canvas, Scrollbar


class ScrollFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.interior = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.vscroll = Scrollbar(
            self, orient='vertical', command=self.canvas.yview
        )

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vscroll.set)
        self.vscroll.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        def config_canvas(ev):
            self.canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'), width=200, height=200
            )

        self.vscroll.pack(fill='y', side='right', expand=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)
        # self.interior.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)  # tried with and without this line, no change
        self.interior.bind('<Configure>', config_canvas)

        self.interior_id = self.canvas.create_window(
            0, 0, window=self.interior, anchor='nw',
        )
```

As far as I know, without using too much magic I have to use a sub-Frame to place widgets on. In my Widget it's self.interior.

If I place one widget on it then everything looks fine, example:

```
label_on_scrollframe = Label(scrollframe_instance.interior)
label_on_scrollframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

But if I add this line then the new widget appears to the right of the scrollbar:

```
label2on_scrollframe = Label(scrollframe_instance.interior)
laber2on_scrollframe.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

The question is, why does it do that and how to fix it?

Comment: No, if you look at the code, the scrollbar isn't placed on interior. I thought that interior is placed on canvas and canvas is placed to the left of scrollbar. This is why I'm confused as to why widgets placed on interior can appear to the right of the scrollbar.

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem, When I cut and paste your exact code, add the tiny bit of code that is missing, the label appears inside the interior frame, just as expected. You are doing everything correctly.

Comment: Yes, this is expected as I stated. However what is unexpected is that if I add another one to the right of that, it appears to the right of the first one AND to the right of the scrollbar.

Comment: Please provide a complete example that illustrates the problem.. I can add dozens of labels just like the first, in dozens of columns, and they all appear to the left of the scrollbar.

Comment: The edited code still does not reproduce the problem. It works exactly as expected. Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I tried it separately too now, before it was tangled into productive code. I inherited from ScrollFrame, maybe that is the cause. I will answer as soon as I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible explanation is that these other widgets are not being created as children of the interior widget.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it didn't work is really embarrassing. I had some code leftover in the productive code which redefined the label that I wanted to place, without making interior its parent.

This question is solved now, thanks to everybody who took the time.